# Adding 3 month when user pick date in android DatePickerDialog

Tags: java, android, datepickerdialog

***This code pick date next is triggered when a button is clicked; and then it adds +3 month to the picked date.***

```
displayDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            DatePickerDialog datepicker = new DatePickerDialog(Remainder.this, android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog_MinWidth, onDateSetListener, year,month,day);
            datepicker.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
            datepicker.show();
        }
    });
    onDateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
            month = month+1;
            Log.d(TAG, "onDateSet: mm/dd/yyyy: " + month + "/" + day + "/" + year);
            String date = month + "/" + day + "/" + year;
            displayDate.setText(date);
        }
    };
```

Comment: can't you say moth+=4

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) class initialized with [`GregorianCalendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html) instance and then use the `Calendar`'s [`add()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#add(int,%20int)) method to add months to your date.

And then use [`get()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#get(int)) method to:

- get the day of the month by: `calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)`
- get the month (range 0-11) by: `calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)`
- get the year by: `calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR)`

To apply this to your code:

```
onDateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
        Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(year, month, day);
        calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH, 3); // adding 3 months
        int newMonth = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
        Log.d(TAG, "onDateSet: mm/dd/yyyy: " +  newMonth + "/" + calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + "/" + calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR));
        String date = newMonth + "/" +  calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + "/" + calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        displayDate.setText(date);
    }
};
```